# Why does this code change both lists (id is not the same)?

Tags: python, list

I have these lists:

```
l1 = [['a2', 1], ['a2', 2], ['a2', 3], ['a2', 4], ['a2', 5]]
membership = [0, 1, 1, 2, 3]
```

I do:

```
l2 = l1[:]
[item.append(membership[i]) for i, item in enumerate(l2)]
```

but both lists now look like:

```
[['a2', 1, 0], ['a2', 2, 1], ['a2', 3, 1], ['a2', 4, 2], ['a2', 5, 3]]
```

I thought `l1[:]` returns a copy? Same behaviour for `l2 = list(l1)`

```
id(l2) == id(l1)
```

returns

```
False
```

Comment: `l1[:]` creates a new list with the same items as `l1`, that is: `id(l1) != id(l2)`, but `id(l1[0]) == id(l2[0])`, `id(l1[1]) == id(l2[1])`, ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`l1[:]` just create a shallow copy of `l1` and it doesn't work for nested list. For nested lists you need [`copy.deepcopy`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/copy.html#copy.deepcopy)

```
>>> import copy
>>> l1 = [['a2', 1], ['a2', 2], ['a2', 3], ['a2', 4], ['a2', 5]]
>>> membership = [0, 1, 1, 2, 3]
>>> l2=copy.deepcopy(l1)
>>> [item.append(membership[i]) for i, item in enumerate(l2)]
[None, None, None, None, None]
>>> l1
[['a2', 1], ['a2', 2], ['a2', 3], ['a2', 4], ['a2', 5]]
>>> l2
[['a2', 1, 0], ['a2', 2, 1], ['a2', 3, 1], ['a2', 4, 2], ['a2', 5, 3]]
>>>
```

*Note*: changing a list within a list comprehension is not a correct way. instead use a normal `for` loop.

```
for i, item in enumerate(l2):
    item.append(membership[i])
```